# Running Protractor through a browser on a remote device

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

We have Selenium running on a test server. We want to run our Protractor tests from a remote device on the same network without having to install anything (e.g. Selenium RemoteWebDriver). We used to do this by running Angular Scenario runner.html, which would execute our e2e tests in the browser via JavaScript.

Does Protractor + Selenium WebDriver allow us to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. WebDriver has to be run through a Driver (chromedriver, iedriver, firefoxdriver), so it can't just be triggered through the browser.

This removes some convenience, but allows for much better native event firing, and means your application doesn't have to serve runner.html somewhere.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought. Thanks!